# Django 0.96 and url

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to get the absolute url of a given action in Django 0.96 (using Google App Engine).

I have this url configuration:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('framework.facebook',(r'^canvas/invite_friends$','views.inviteFriends'),
)
```

In my template:

```
window._url = '{% url views.inviteFriends %}';
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for url is package.package.module.function args so if you replace 'views' with your module/ application name it should work.

```
{% url app_name.inviteFriends %}
```

An example:

If the full path to your function is myproject.myapp.views.inviteFriends code would be:

```
 {% url myapp.inviteFriends %}
```

or

```
{% url myproject.myapp.inviteFriends %}
```

Comment: I've also tried with the full path to the package and that doesn't work.

Comment: What is the complete path to your view function?